# Unable to click on line under text

Tags: selenium

I am trying to click on a line under the text but its not clicking on it and also not showing error.

website name voylla.com

```java
package newpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class seven {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\h\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String baseUrl = "http://www.voylla.com";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.className("dropdown"));

    //WebElement submenu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#main-div > div.mdl-tabs.mdl-js-tabs.mdl-js-ripple-effect.mdl-js-ripple-effect--ignore-events.is-upgraded > div > div > div > div:nth-child(7)"));

    WebElement sub = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main-div\"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[7]/a"));
    Hover(driver, menu);

    HoverAndClick(driver, sub, sub);
  }

  public static void Hover(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(element).perform();
  }

  public static void HoverAndClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement elementToHover, WebElement elementToClick) {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(elementToHover).click(elementToClick).build().perform();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Actions methods for click()? any reasons?

Comment: to click on a hover element